# Is there an way to call an client.on?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I wanna make sort of an reaction game and it need the functions message,reactions and user for it, is there an way i can call another client.on (in my case bot.on) function from another one?
(irrelevant parts of the code are missing)

[first client.on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15Zld.png)

[second client.on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbPCc.png)

[subfunction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep3wR.png)

```
bot.on('message', function (message) {
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        var fetchedMessages = message.channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 99 });
        var args = message.content.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];
        args = args.splice(1);
        switch (cmd) {
            case 'react':
                messageReactionAdd()
                break;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (message,reaction, user) => {
    minigames.reaction(message,user,reaction)
});

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

module.exports = {
    reaction: function (reaction,message) {
        var reacted =
        message.channel.send("Auf die Plätze").then(function(message){
            setTimeout(function () {message.edit("Fertig ?")  }, 5000)
            setTimeout(function () {message.edit("LOS!")  }, 10000)
            setTimeout(function () {message.react("")  }, 10000)
            setTimeout(function () {message.edit("STOP ")  }, 17000)
            setTimeout(function () {  }, 1000)
        })
        if(reaction.emoji.name === "") {
            console.log(reaction.users);
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Discord.js [Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) is really an [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) instance. [`emitter.on()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener) attaches a listener that'll be invoked when the defined event is emitted. To emit the event in the first place, use the [`emitter.emit()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_emit_eventname_args) method, like so...

```js
emitter.emit('event', ...parameters);
```

For example...

```js
bot.emit('messageReactionAdd', reaction, user);
```